# Open a View Controller from a UITableViewCell Without a Segue

Tags: ios, uitableview, viewcontroller

I need to open a view controller from a UITableViewCell without a segue. I don't need code examples just the concept. I have tried calling the UITabBarController so that I can call it from any view with this cell but I get:

> Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Can someone help me figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You present a view controller with...

```
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent
                     animated:(BOOL)flag
                   completion:(void (^)(void))completion
```

and then dismiss it with...

```
- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag
                           completion:(void (^)(void))completion
```